# Can document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] ever return null?

Tags: javascript, dom

I use the following code to run a script:

```
var js = document.createElement('script');
js.src = 'http://xxx./yyy.js';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
```

Will this code work in all kinds of browsers? For example, I'm afraid that if the `head` tag does not exist for whatever reason, I'll get a 'null object' error.

But the fact is, I have tested on some browsers, no error happened.

So, please expert tell me , will this work around for all browsers?

Comment: This isn't really an issue/problem.... Stackoverflow is for programming problems. You will have to test your own development or research limitations on creating dynamic script tags.

Comment: The only problem I see is the Case issue in `getelementsbytagname` it should be `getElementsByTagName` - Pascal Casing http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PascalCase

Comment: `scrip` should be `script`, `getelementsbytagname` should be `getElementsByTagName` and `.appendChild()` should be `.appendChild(js)`

Answer (score 0):

It's [possible](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#dom-document-head) for `document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]` (and `document.head`) to return `null` if there's no `<head>` in the document, e.g. after someone does this:

```
document.head.parentNode.removeChild(document.head);
```

On the other hand, omitting the `<head>` in HTML source code should **not** lead to this in "HTML5"-compliant parsers, as they're [required to insert it for you](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#the-before-head-insertion-mode). (I wouldn't expect older browsers to be different, but it's impossible to be sure about all versions of all browsers on any input.)

If you're happy with having [the same browser support as jQuery 2](https://jquery.com/browser-support/), you might be relieved to know they [use `head` without null-checking](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core/DOMEval.js).